# Why do `rlang::sym` and `rlang::quo_name` in LHS of expression behave similarly?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

Call the function below using `foo(c("b"))`. The outputs are shown inline.

I'm confused as to why both (1) `df %>% mutate(!!x_ := 100 + !!x))` and (2) `df %>% mutate(!!x := 100 + !!x))` work identically; based on [dplyr programming recipes](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#programming-recipes) only (1) should work.

```
foo <- function(variables) {

  x <- rlang::sym(variables[[1]])

  x_ <- quo_name(x)

  print(x)
  #> b

  print(typeof(x))
  #> [1] "symbol"

  print(x_)
  #> [1] "b"

  print(typeof(x_))
  #> [1] "character"

  df <- data_frame(a = 1, b = 2)

  print(df %>% mutate(!!x_ := 100 + !!x))

  #> # A tibble: 1 x 2
  #>         a     b
  #>       <dbl> <dbl>
  #>   1     1   102  

  print(df %>% mutate(!!x := 100 + !!x))

  #> # A tibble: 1 x 2
  #>         a     b
  #>       <dbl> <dbl>
  #>   1     1   102  

}
```

Comment: As per mentioned in the [documentation](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#setting-variable-names) you are referring to: *The rules on the LHS are slightly different: the unquoted operand should evaluate to a string or a symbol*. It works because  `x_` is a character.

Comment: You are right! I missed the "...or a symbol" part. If move the comment to an answer I can go ahead and accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving comment to answer.

As per mentioned in the [documentation](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#setting-variable-names) you are referring to:

> The rules on the `LHS` are slightly different: the unquoted operand
>   should evaluate to a **string or a symbol**.

Here, it works because `x_` is, in fact, a character.